# Symfony 2.8 : Get message command using Process in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a file command handling data add database . I use Document Symfony 2.8 **`Process`** for the handling in the controller.
Everything was running fine. But I got an error . In the file command I use **`if-else`** to check data. When processed and running **`$process->run()`** , I cannot get the error in **`else`** (in else. I use `echo` to show the error).

```
if (!empty($id)) {
  // handling code
} else {
 echo "not found Id"
}
```

Do you have any ideas? help me please !

Document i use : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: Off-topic but always be careful when viewing the Symfony docs to use the correct version number.  2.8 is quite old and unsupported.  Things changes over time and it is easy to get confused.  The correct link is: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/process.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly you can get the output of the process by using : `echo $process->getOutput();` or in your case you can throw exception like

```
if (!empty($id)) {
    // handling code
} else {
    throw new \Exception('Id not found');
}
```

and put your process within try catch block like that

```
try {
    $process->mustRun();

    echo $process->getOutput();
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```